# How to express multi-condition for str_remove?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a messy dataset which is composed by many kinds of notes, like `A1-2`, `C12.3`. The worse part is that they are not of consistence.

Was trying to remove them by stringr::str_remove, by adding `[[:punct]]`,but seems not working on all condition. It seems impossible to solve all issue in one line, but have to treat one by one.

Would like to ask for advice.

```
DT <- c("A1", "A1","A3-12", "A200.4", "AX3-15", "B18", "F16", "Z32-1", "E300--2", "C61","TXDS")

str_remove(DT, pattern="[-][0-9][0-9]")
str_remove(DT, pattern="[[:punct:]][0-9][0-9]")
Target <- c("A1", "A1.1","A3", "A200", "AX3", "B18", "F16", "Z32", "E300", "C61","TXDS")
# hoping the result of identical(Target, DT) is TRUE
```

Comment: @RonakShah Sorry, my bad. should be `A1`.

Comment: I think you changed your input (`DT`) instead of output (`Target`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place the `-` and `.` in square brackets to match either of them literally and other characters that succeed (`.*`), in the replacement, specify blank (`""`)

```
sub("[-.].*", "", DT)
#[1] "A1"   "A1"   "A3"   "A200" "AX3"  "B18"  "F16"  "Z32"  "E300" "C61"  "TXDS"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple `sub` call will do. This removes everything after `-` OR `.`.

```
sub("-.*|\\..*", "", DT)
#[1] "A1"   "A1"   "A3"   "A200" "AX3"  "B18"  "F16"  "Z32"  "E300" "C61"  "TXDS"
```

Comment: Thanks, will try immediately.